# How can i shuffle the two arrays using functions so that it would print out a random card

Tags: python, arrays, function, shuffle

I wanted it to print a random card by shuffling it through functions
for example 4 of hearts
this is current code i had and it kept printing None of None

Thanks in advance

```
def exchange(SUITS, i, suits):
    temp = SUITS[i]
    SUITS[i] = SUITS[suits]
    SUITS[suits] = temp
    return SUITS[suits]

def shuffle():
    SUITS = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts' , 'Spades']
    n = len(SUITS)
    for i in range(n):
        suits = random.randrange(0,n)
        exchange(SUITS,i, suits)

def exchange2(RANKS, i, ranks):
    Temp = RANKS[i]
    RANKS[i] = RANKS[ranks]
    RANKS[ranks] = Temp
    return RANKS[ranks]

def shuffle2():
    RANKS = ['2', ' 3', '4', '5', '6' , '7' , '8', '9','10',
        'Jack', 'Queen', 'King','Ace']
    n = len(RANKS)
    for i in range(n):
        ranks = random.randrange(0,n)
        exchange2(RANKS,i, ranks)
        
w = shuffle()
z = shuffle2()


print(str(z) + ' of ' + str(w))
```

Comment: `shuffle()` and `shuffle2()` don't _return_ anything, therefore they return `None` by default.

Comment: Perhaps this is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65045702/9473764

Comment: hey john what do you think i should put instead

Answer (score 0):

python random library has a [shuffle()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_shuffle.asp) function for lists also your function is not returning anything so your print statement will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could understand in your problem statement I guess you can simply do it as below:

```
import random

def shuffle():
    SUITS = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts' , 'Spades']
    RANKS = ['2', ' 3', '4', '5', '6' , '7' , '8', '9','10',
        'Jack', 'Queen', 'King','Ace']
    randomSuit = random.randrange(0, len(SUITS))
    randomRank = random.randrange(0, len(RANKS))
    print(RANKS[randomRank] + " of " + SUITS[randomSuit])
    
    
shuffle()
```

Let me know if this is what you were expecting.

If you want to get the rank and suit from different functions then it can be slightly modified to achieve that as well.

```
import random

def shuffleRank():
    RANKS = ['2', ' 3', '4', '5', '6' , '7' , '8', '9','10',
        'Jack', 'Queen', 'King','Ace']
    randomRank = random.randrange(0, len(RANKS))
    return RANKS[randomRank] 
    
def shuffleSuit():
    SUITS = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts' , 'Spades']
    randomSuit = random.randrange(0, len(SUITS))
    return SUITS[randomSuit]


print (shuffleRank() + " of " + shuffleSuit())
```